# Is there a way to make someone disappear in Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

in Tumblr, is there a way to make someone disappear (a.k.a blocked) without them knowing you blocked them? If you normally block someone: yes, they will disappear and you don't see their posts or likes or comments anymore, but sadly they can notice you blocked them because they can't see you either.

There are some people/accounts who I don't want to see. I don't follow them, but I see them often because they are in the same circle that I am. E.g I see them leave comments for tumblrs I follow, hence I constantly see them.

I just can't stand certain people, but I don't want to be mean/ass to anyone. I just don't want them to exist for me from my point of view.

Tumblr savior doesn't seem to be help for this. Any other program or add on? Thanks for reading.